# How can "start" be used in past continuous?

Tags: past-continuous

Another multiple-choice question:

> What were you doing when Lucy phoned you?
> I had just finished my work and _____ to read a book.

The answer is "was starting." I think the answer is wrong by itself. Since "start" is a transient verb, it can't be used in past continuous.

---

I've made a mistake, which is not the focus of the question, by writing present continuous instead of past continuous.

---

"The action of starting a car continues until the car has started and you release the starter." but I think it happens too fast to be considered a continuous event.

Comment: Yes it is fine. Random example I made up: "I was just starting to think you wouldn't come!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Please be aware that the question has been edited and it is significantly different to when I answered it

---

I had just finished my work and **was starting** to read a book.

Q. **The answer is "was starting." I think the answer is wrong by itself. Since "start" is a transient verb, it can't be used in present continuous.**

I would suggest that the answer is correct

---

**transient**; adjective; lasting for only a short time; temporary:

Although an action may only last for a short time it may be continuous whilst it is happening. Temporary & Continuous are not mutually exclusive. The action of walking continues until you stop walking. The action of starting a car continues until the car has started and you release the starter.

Starting the car, Starting the race, starting a war

---

Q. **How can “start” used in present continuous?**    *How can “start” be used in the Present Continuous Tense?*

**Present Continuous:** form; We use am, are, is + the -ing form of the verb

**I am starting the car.**

However in this case I think you are confusing the Present Continuous with the Past Continuous

**Past continuous**: form; We use **was**/were + the -ing form of the verb.

"I had just finished my work and **was starting** to read a book".

**Past continuous**: uses; Events happening at a particular time in the past
We generally use the past continuous to talk about actions and states in progress (happening) around a particular time in the past. It can emphasise that the action or state continued for a period of time in the past:

Where was Donna last night? *I’m not sure. I think she was visiting her family*. (action)
or
*I remember that night. You were wearing that red dress*. (state)

Ref CED [Past continuous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past-continuous-i-was-working?q=Past%20continuous%3A%20form)

---

Ref CED [present participle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/present-participle?q=) [-ing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ing)

**-ing**: used to form the present participle of regular verbs:

**present participle**; a form of a verb that in English ends in -ing and comes after another verb to show continuous action. It is used to form the present continuous:
In the sentences "The children are watching television", "The weather is getting colder", and **"I heard him singing"**, "watching", "getting", and "singing" **are present participles.**

Comment: "The action of starting a car continues until the car has started and you release the starter." but I think it happens too fast to be considered a continuous event.

Comment: Starting a race is even faster. "The race is starting".

Comment: @mirthspritzsultryobscurantism. I think your problem is that you are taking the name of the tense literally, please look at the dictionary definition "the past continuous"; Noun [ S ] (also the past progressive) the grammatical form used for an action that someone was doing or an event that was happening at a particular time. If it is helpful to your understanding please use the other name for the Tense of  "past progressive"

Comment: "I was starting to read a book" could be interpreted as "I was reading one of the first few pages." The verb can refer to the early stages of a process as well as the actual moment of beginning.